# Arrange textbox and label vertically bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

New to bootstrap, tried a lot of things, but not able to align the text box and label vertically next to each other above the text area.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Estimate ID: 265</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-inline ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Job Title:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Location:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Location">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Approved Reference:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Reference">
    </div>

  </div>



    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Description:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Not more than 100 characters" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>


http://jsfiddle.net/6xH5s/66/
```

Should I add custom css, is it not possible with the bootstrap css files?

Answer (score 0):

As a novice you should read the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and learn about their grid system, it's very useful.

Your [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/6xH5s/68/).

```
   <style>
h2 {
    margin-top: -1px;
}


</style>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">


   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Estimate ID: 265</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-inline ">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <label for="email">Job Title:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <label for="pwd">Location:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Location">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <label for="email">Approved Reference:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Reference">
    </div>
</div>
  </div>


    <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
  <label for="comment">Description:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Not more than 100 characters" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>




</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Will surely have a read.
However I am trying to achieve something like this ..

Title: *Textbox* Location:*Textbox* Reference: *Textbox*

The entire 3 inputs in a single row.

Comment: Updated the answer @macro32  please check

Comment: Sorry, I think Iam not clear, how to make the textbox go parallel with the naming label.

Name : Adam

So that I can get all the 3 inputs in a straight line.